# Adding in a Search feature to a code swap challenge

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am participating into a code swap type challenge, for Java and Spring, and I am having some issues adding in a Search feature for this shopping list app. Before I get into depth of code, by search feature I mean search the local database, not something like google.  Now I'l show the code and then explain what I'm trying to do underneath it all.

This is the error message:

```
2016-12-14 10:00:40.476  WARN 10452 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl        : Unrecognized hbm2ddl_auto value : auto.  Supported values include create, create-drop, update, and validate.  Ignoring
2016-12-14 10:00:42.300  INFO 10452 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-12-14 10:00:46.009  WARN 10452 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'shoppingListController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'shoppingListRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shoppingListRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property category found for type ShoppingList!
2016-12-14 10:00:46.014  INFO 10452 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-12-14 10:00:46.071  INFO 10452 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-12-14 10:00:46.393  INFO 10452 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2016-12-14 10:00:46.455 ERROR 10452 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'shoppingListController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'shoppingListRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shoppingListRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property category found for type ShoppingList!
```

This is the part of the controller I am editing:

```
@GetMapping("/lists")
    public String lists(Model model, @RequestParam(name = "srch-term", required = false) String searchTerm) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String email = auth.getName();
        User u = userRepo.findOneByEmail(email);
        if (searchTerm == null || "".equals(searchTerm)) {
            model.addAttribute("lists", shoppingListRepo.findAllByUser(u));
        } else {
            ArrayList<ShoppingList> userLists = new ArrayList<ShoppingList>();
            ArrayList<ShoppingList> lists = shoppingListRepo.findByCategoryContainsOrNameContainsAllIgnoreCase(searchTerm,
                    searchTerm);
            for (ShoppingList list : lists) {
                if (list.getUser() == u) {
                    userLists.add(list);
                }
            }
        model.addAttribute("lists", shoppingListRepo.findAllByUser(u));
        model.addAttribute("user", u);
        }
        return "lists";
    }
```

This is the controller before being edited by me

```
@GetMapping("/lists")
    public String lists(Model model) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String email = auth.getName();
        User u = userRepo.findOneByEmail(email);
        model.addAttribute("lists", shoppingListRepo.findAllByUser(u));
        model.addAttribute("user", u);
        return "lists";
    }
```

This is my Repository

```
package org.elevenfifty.shoppinglist.repositories;

import java.util.ArrayList;


import org.elevenfifty.shoppinglist.beans.ShoppingList;
import org.elevenfifty.shoppinglist.beans.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ShoppingListRepository extends CrudRepository<ShoppingList, Long> {

    ArrayList<ShoppingList> findAllByUser(User u);

    ArrayList<ShoppingList> findByCategoryContainsOrNameContainsAllIgnoreCase(String categoryPart, String namePart);


}
```

Now like I said I am getting a search feature working. I am not sure where the property is in my error message I am hoping some fresh eyes can help find what I am clearly missing.

Comment: There is no such field as `category` in your `ShoppingList` entity.

Comment: Thank Abdullah! i figured it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Add category field and its getters and setters to the ShoppingList class.

```
private String category

public void setCategory(String category){
    this.category = category;
}

public String getCategory(){
    return category;
}
```